Playwright manual download with default file names
I use Playwright to partially automate my tasks but sometimes I need to navigate manually to get to the info I require. As such, I need to download files manually as well, but there doesn't seem to be a way to save those files as their default names.
I know if the download is started from the script, I might be able to use suggested_filename, but in this case, I am triggering the download manually.
How can I add a global override to name files by their suggested_filename and not a GUID? Preferably starting from this example code.
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, Playwright

async def run(playwright: Playwright):
    chromium = playwright.chromium # or "firefox" or "webkit".
    browser = await chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.new_page()
    await asyncio.sleep(9999)

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        await run(playwright)
asyncio.run(main())


Please share a [mcve] so we can see how you're doing these downloads. Thanks.

@ggorlen Opening a browser the same way as in their tutorial, then time.sleep

@ggorlen it is the first chunk, added it into the question.

Right--I don't see any download code in there I can run and reproduce a problem with.

edited the code slightly, you can just search any thing and download any file, the file names becomes GUID instead of the actual file name with extension.

You can change the download behavior in Chrome by sending the Page.setDownloadBehavior command.
session = browser.new_browser_cdp_session()
session.send(
            "Page.setDownloadBehavior", 
            {
               'behavior': 'allow',
               'downloadPath': 'C:/Users/Me/Downloads/custom/folder/'
            })


I assume this means that this can't be achieved in the regular session?

@weasel this is a regular session. The session used by playwright is not exposed.

Does the code look something like this? Also I assume you copied your code from js?
        browser = await chromium.launch()
        await browser.new_browser_cdp_session()
        await browser.send(
            "Page.setDownloadBehavior",
            {
               "behavior": 'allow',
               "downloadPath": 'path
            })
        context = await browser.new_context(viewport={"width": 1920, "height": 1080})```

Yes I did. Fixed :) Did that work?

nope that didn't work, also did you mean Browser.setDownloadBehavior?

You can also try Browser.setDownloadBehavior

nope that doesn't work either

maybe with library
https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html
example
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
urlretrieve(link_url, 'path_to_your_folder/give_me_a_name.pdf')


unfortunately I am looking for a way to override all download behaviour, as I am downloading the files manually and not programmatically

in this case, create a file listener locally and rename the files, based on conditions
